# CakePHP 3.7 cakephp/authentication plugin. Error "Authentication is required to continue "

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am following the guideline inside the cook book https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1.1/en/index.html. However my code keeps throwing errors [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2d4Z.png)

This is my Application.php

```php
<?php
/**
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (https://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link      https://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since     3.3.0
 * @license   https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
namespace App;

/**
 * AUTHENTICATION SETTINGS
 */
use Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Authentication\AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface;
use Authentication\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware;

/**
 * AUTHENTICATION SETTINGS
 */
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Core\Exception\MissingPluginException;
use Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware;
use Cake\Http\BaseApplication;
use Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware;
use Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware;
use Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;





/**
 * Application setup class.
 *
 * This defines the bootstrapping logic and middleware layers you
 * want to use in your application.
 */
//OLD -- class Application extends BaseApplication

class Application extends BaseApplication
implements AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */

     public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response)
     {
         $service = new AuthenticationService();

         $fields = [
             'username' => 'email',
             'password' => 'password'
         ];

         // Load identifiers
         $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', compact('fields'));

         // Load the authenticators, you want session first
         $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
         $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
             'fields' => $fields,
             'loginUrl' => '/users/login'
         ]);

         return $service;
     }

    public function bootstrap()
    {

        parent::bootstrap();
        $this->addPlugin('DebugKit');
        $this->addPlugin('Authentication');

        // Call parent to load bootstrap from files.
        //-- Authentication plugin added change the Auth function


        if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
            try {
                $this->addPlugin('Bake');
            } catch (MissingPluginException $e) {
                // Do not halt if the plugin is missing
            }

            $this->addPlugin('Migrations');
        }

        /*
         * Only try to load DebugKit in development mode
         * Debug Kit should not be installed on a production system
         */
        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            $this->addPlugin(\DebugKit\Plugin::class);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Setup the middleware queue your application will use.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue $middlewareQueue The middleware queue to setup.
     * @return \Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue The updated middleware queue.
     */
    public function middleware($middlewareQueue)
    {
        $middlewareQueue
            // Catch any exceptions in the lower layers,
            // and make an error page/response
            ->add(new ErrorHandlerMiddleware(null, Configure::read('Error')))

            // Handle plugin/theme assets like CakePHP normally does.
            ->add(new AssetMiddleware([
                'cacheTime' => Configure::read('Asset.cacheTime')
            ]))

            // Add routing middleware.
            // Routes collection cache enabled by default, to disable route caching
            // pass null as cacheConfig, example: `new RoutingMiddleware($this)`
            // you might want to disable this cache in case your routing is extremely simple
            ->add(new RoutingMiddleware($this, '_cake_routes_'));


         // Add the authentication middleware
         $authentication = new AuthenticationMiddleware($this,[
           'unauthorizedRedirect' => '/',
           'queryParam' => null,
         ]);


         // Add the middleware to the middleware queue
         $middlewareQueue->add($authentication);

        return $middlewareQueue;
    }
}
```

Inside my app/Application.php i have call the *Authentication* plugin inside *function bootstrap* like so

```php
    public function bootstrap()
    {

        parent::bootstrap();
        $this->addPlugin('DebugKit');
        $this->addPlugin('Authentication');
```

and inside my *AppController.php* i have set it up like this

```php
/** INITIALIZE  **/
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
            'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
        ]);
        /**
        *$this->loadComponent('Flash');
        *
         * load authenticator
         * [$this->loadComponent description]
         * @var [type]
         *
         */
         $this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication', [
             'logoutRedirect' => false // Default is false
         ]);


/** INITIALIZE  **/

}
```

and my *UsersController.php* the one that handles the request coming from https:localhost/users/login

```php
    public function login()
     {

       //$this->render(false);



      $this->viewBuilder()->layout('Common/login');
    $session = $this->request->session();

      /*
      **AUTHENTICATION
       */
       $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
      debug($result);

          // regardless of POST or GET, redirect if user is logged in
          if ($result->isValid()) {
              $user = $request->getAttribute('identity');

              // Persist the user into configured authenticators.
              $this->Authentication->setIdentity($user);
              $session->write('user_data',$user);

              $redirect = $this->request->getQuery('redirect', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'display', 'index']);
              return $this->redirect($redirect);
          }

          // display error if user submitted and authentication failed
          if ($this->request->is(['post']) && !$result->isValid()) {
              $this->Flash->error('Invalid username or password');
          }
       /*
       **AUTHENTICATION
        */

    }
```

I have been at it for hours, need help on this one guys :) .

Comment: Apparently you're not authenticated, ie authentication failed or wasn't performed. You're not showing that you're excluding the `login` action from the actions that require authentication!? Also there's output from your bootstrap (and possibly your login action) which will cause the session cookie header to not be sent. Besides, manually persisting the identity isn't required, the authentication service does that automatically.

Comment: do i need to create a controller that will display login form that will send data to /users/login ?

Comment: If you want to use a form, sure, then you need a controller that displays one. Normally the controller you already have there would render the form in the login action. But again, you don't seem to exclude the `login` action fro the actions that require authentication (or maybe you're just not showing all the code).

Comment: are You using 3.x version or 1.x? It seems you asked for 3.x question but using a 1.x code doccumentation. For 3.x: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe the documentation relates to the official Authentication plugin which is the new way of authenticating CakePHP apps. The current version is 1.1 which requires a minimum of CakePHP 3.7. The documentation you have linked to is being deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define allow action for non authorized actions in beforeFilter, for example:

`$this->Authentication->allowUnauthenticated(['login']);`